# Recreate a Php Web Session in Cli Script started by the web script

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a php application created using Zend framework 1.12. There is a Zend action which runs a php cli script. The session_id is passed to the cli script as argument.

Zend Bootstrap.php which is shared by the web application and the cli script.

```
    protected function _initSession()
    {
        global $argv;

        $this->bootstrap('database');

        if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'testing') {
            require_once 'Zend/Session.php';
            Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
            return;
        }

        $config = array(
            'name' => 'session',
            'primary' => 'session_id',
            'modifiedColumn' => 'modified',
            'dataColumn' => 'data',
            'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
        );

        Zend_Session::writeClose(); //cancel the session's auto start,important

        $saveHandler = new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config);
        Zend_Session::setSaveHandler($saveHandler);

        if (defined('APPLICATION_TYPE')
                      && (APPLICATION_TYPE == 'cli' ||
                          APPLICATION_TYPE == 'standalone')) {

            //Restore the session and then start it. job_id:session
            $d = explode(':', $argv[1]);

            if (count($d) > 1) {
                $job_id = $d[1];
                if (!empty($job_id)) {
                    Zend_Session::setId($job_id);
                }
            }
        }

        Zend_Session::start();

        return null;
    }
```

I have a session saved from the web script which I would like to access in the cli script.

The setup works on a mac using php version 5.5.14. It does not work on a linux server with php version 5.3.10

Any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was with suhosin. The default option for suhosin is to encrypt the session id. I had to set encrypt to off.

suhosion.session.encrypt = off